# How to get notifications when Google Compute Engine automatically migrate an instance

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I want to be alerted when instances are migrated. I can see the list of operations in Console (http://d.pr/i/16fpz), but how to get it in realtime (via email or in Slack)?

Comment: Hmm... Why this question is being downvoted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [Google Cloud Logging](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/) to create a log based Metric and set an alert on that metric using Google Cloud Monitoring. You can refer to this [link](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/logs_based_metrics#create_a_metric) for steps and more details. However, one thing to keep in mind is that Google Cloud Logging is Beta release and is not covered by any SLA.

Answer (score -2):

When Autohealing is enabled for instance group, the instances are shuts down when  health check fails. 
In that case you can attach a shutdown script with the instances that can be used for any purpose.

Comment: I don't see how that would be applicable to a question about migrations.